# Knockout 3.4.0 deferUpdates and reevaluation count

Tags: knockout.js

I'm migrating a complex web app that relies extensively on Knockout.js to the new 3.4.0 version to be able to implement components, and to profit of the new performance improvement which the new deferUpdates option offers, by reading the Knockout documentation:

> Using deferred updates ensures that computed observables and bindings
>   are updated only after their dependencies are stable.

Now, surprisingly i have situations where my dependent observables are instead reevaluated more times as before, which causes more UI redraws than before.

This is an example of a classic optimization for observableArrays that result in just one reevaluation in older KO versions and in the new 3.4.0 *without* deferUpdates switched on:

```
this.items = ko.observableArray();
this.addNewData = function() {
  var items = ko.utils.arrayMap(Items, function(item) {
    return new Item(item.name, item.priority);
  });
  //take advantage of push accepting variable arguments
  self.items.push.apply(self.items, items);
};
this.addNewData();
```

Now, by setting:

```
ko.options.deferUpdates = true;
```

there are two reevaluations, one at observableArray creation:

```
this.items = ko.observableArray();
```

and the second when data is provided, by invoking addNewData().

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kkrgjbsr/

Instead, just to explain more in detail what is happen, following observableArray initialization would cause just only one single reevaluation, as it would be good for me:

```
this.items = ko.observableArray([
    new Item(Items[0]),
    new Item(Items[1]),
    ...and so on
]);
```

Could someone please kindly explain how to keep the performance improvement of deferUpdates, because there are part of my application where i absolutely need it, and at the same time avoid these unwanted reevaluations?

BTW, is there a way to track in a whole application where the reevaluation count will increase by switching on deferUpdates?

Thanks everybody in advance

Please note:

- i would prefer not to use the rateLimit extender, nor specify a fixed period of time, as i'm not sure if this would provide always just one reevaluation.
- i would prefer not to extend individually each single observable with deferredUpdates, because i have hundreds of them, and i cannot exactly foresee where the code will break

Comment: The point that I don't understand is this: During creation `this.items = ko.observableArray();` there are by definition no subscribers, so I don't see how that would make any kind of difference. A runnable code sample that demonstrates the problem would in context be very helpful.

Comment: Hi tomalak, i spent several hours to isolate the problem.and i was sadly surprised to find out where it lies..:-) but, if you see my fiddle, please think the dependantComputed as a switch for components, so when it changes two times, there are two component redraw. Hope i am now more clear. THX

Comment: As a *side note*, [this question on pushing multiple items at once](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23606541/419956) might also be of interest to you.

Comment: You should always set `deferEvaluation` to true in your computeds. I'm not sure it will address all your concerns, but it takes care of the Fiddle. http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computed-reference.html#constructing-a-computed-observable

Comment: @Jeroen: yes, i know the "trick" with the underlinyngArray - but: is there a way to pass a variable length of items directly to the costructor of an observableArray? The example in the Knockcout documentation "Prepopulating an observable array" shows only literals http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, that's what i found out:

*ko.options.deferUpdates=true* creates this one more reevaluation only during the initialization of the viewmodel.

To pass the data to the observableArray constructor, simply use the utility function arrayMap - no hassle there:

```
this.items = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(Items, function(item) {
  return new Item(item.name, item.priority);
}));
```

In my special case, the unwanted side effect of the increased reevaluation count was hard to recognize because has only affected the UI redraw - not the data - and led to an unexpected performance degradation.

Moreover, i tested also rniemeyer's fiddle "Reevaluating computed observables" with the new 3.4.0 Knockout version and deferUpdates switched on - even the "Add New Bad" button shows just only 1 reevaluation count (sorry if i tested the obvious).

Now, i always switch the new option deferUpdates on, as this is a brilliant and indispensable performance improvement, and most of the optimizations required in the older KO versions are no longer necessary  - the only annoying thing is, that in some special circumstancies some of these optimizations **must** be removed.

Comment: For reference, this issue was reported in a slightly different context: https://github.com/knockout/knockout/pull/2163. A fix should go out in the next release.