# How do I replace the contents of knockout js observable array with an array returned from a promise

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, promise

I am trying to replace the contents of an observable array with an array that is returned from a promise.

I initialize an observable array like so

```
let contents = ko.observableArray([]);
```

And the array that is returned from the promise looks something like this

```
[{name : test, code : 0, country : UK}]
```

How can replace the empty observable array with the contents of the array that is returned from the promise?

I have tried this

```
promise.then(array => {contents(array)});
```

As well as this

```
promise.then(function(value){contents(value)})
```

but neither of them add anything into the observable array.

Comment: I can't duplicate your problem with a [simple example](https://codepen.io/erikphilips/pen/wROmbN?editors=1010).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28358715/8501494)

you should first delete its content (if any) through observableArray method called removeAll.

```js
// empty the array
contents.removeAll()

// insert the new array values
promise.then(array => {ko.utils.arrayPushAll(contents, array)});

// or
promise.then(function(value){ko.utils.arrayPushAll(contents, value)});
```